# Bash, loop within a loop doesn't run command for each iteration?

Tags: bash

I am writing a simple bash script where I loop through folders, then within those folders I loop through subfolders and execute a separate command. 
Echoing the names of the subfolders seems to work but trying to execute a command called summary.sh (which just summarizes random stuff, not important) it only does it for the first subfolder which is Folder_A.1.

Below is my script and a sample output. Also here is a tree form of my folders:

```
Current Directory:

Folder_A
   |
   ----Folder_A.1
   ----Folder_A.2
   ----Folder_A.3
Folder_B
   |
   ----Folder_B.1
   ----Folder_B.2
   ----Folder_B.3
Folder_C
  |
   ----Folder_C.1
   ----Folder_C.2
   ----Folder_C.3
```

My bash script:

```
my_pwd=$PWD

for dirname in $my_pwd/Folder*
do
    folder=$(basename "$dirname")
    echo $folder
done
```

So if I just run this first loop alone the output in my terminal is as follows:

```
Folder_A
Folder_B
Folder_C
```

Then I include a second loop because I really want to get the subfolder names:

```
my_pwd=$PWD

for dirname in $my_pwd/Folder*
do
    folder=$(basename "$dirname")
    for subfolders in $my_pwd/$folder/*
    do
       subfoldname=$(basename "$subfolders")
       #echo $subfoldname
       ./summary.sh $subfoldname
    done
done
```

However, only one subfolder gets executed which is Folder_A.1. It's weird becuase if I keep the echo $subfoldname and remove the summary.sh line, I get this output:

```
Folder_A.1
Folder_A.2
Folder_A.3
etc.
```

Which is fine as it means I am accessing each subfolder which is what I want. Normally I would cd into a folder (i.e. Folder_A) and run summary.sh in terminal as follows:

```
\Folder_A> summary.sh Folder_A.1
```

And I repeat for each subfolder. Then I cd to the next main folder (i.e. Folder_B), and execute summary.sh for each subfolder. Hence, I am trying to optimize this as a bash script so I don't need to do it manually.

Comment: As an aside, you're going to have a bunch of bugs here if your names contain spaces. You want `"$my_pwd"/Folder*`. And why would you use `basename` only to tack the directory name back on afterwards?

Comment: Run your code through http://shellcheck.net/, fix what it flags, and then run `bash -x yourscript` to log each command the script runs during execution; that'll do a lot of good towards identifying the specific point of failure.

Comment: They don't have spaces and this part of the script has worked fine. I just cannot seem to get summary.sh to execute for each subfolder, it only does it for the first occurrence and then stops.

Comment: I don't suppose you're running `set -e` earlier in the script? (And just because it's "worked fine" doesn't mean it's bug-free; that just means you haven't yet tested with sufficiently interesting inputs).

Comment: BTW, why not just `for subfolder in "$PWD"/*/*/; do`, and avoid the extra layer in the first place?

Comment: Oh originally I wanted to do something else with the first set of Folders and summarize names, but then I didn't and starting only thinking about the subfolders. It just never crossed my mind! I also finished shellcheck.net and added the quotes around variable names and no other issues were found.

Comment: btw, another thing I'd suggest is some statements for debugging purposes. If you put in a line like `: "$my_pwd"/Folder*` directly above the `for dirname in "$my_pwd"/Folder*`, for example, then when you run your script with `bash -x` you'll see a line logging the results of the expansion, so you can see what the glob actually expanded to; do the same for the subfolder list, and you can see how many times each loop *should* run if not interrupted, based on the actual real-world glob expansion results.

Comment: I am not using set -e in the script. I changed the script so it is just the one loop going into each subdirectory, and I can see almost all the correct output in the terminal (a separate bash window opens up) but I actually don't get my summary txt files output anywhere. The summary.sh script just leaves a simple text file with some summary data. I've never ran into this problem before.

Comment: From what you've said, I'm pretty sure this is actually a problem with summary.sh, not with this script.

Comment: Why would that be? It works fine if I run it alone in terminal. I have been trying some stuff out and it's weird i am only getting output in terminal now and I have no clue why it's even doing that. Oh boy..

Comment: Please @-notify me after you've [edit]ed either a `set -x` trace or a standalone reproducer / [mcve] (shortest possible code that does everything necessary, such as creating directories, to let others run the code and see the problem themselves if copied/pasted) into the question. Until anyone but you can see the problem actually happen, we're left to speculation, which isn't a worthwhile use of anyone's time.